# No thumbnail migrations appear - Django 2.2 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-migrations, sorl-thumbnail

I did step by step to implement `sorl-thumbnail` in my Django project. But no `migrations thumbnail` created so images do not get added via sending form but still get added by `admin interface`.

I use:

- Python 3.9
- Django 2.2.16
- Pillow 9.3.0
- sorl-thumbnail 12.9.0

What I did.

`pip install pillow, sorl-thumbnail`

In `INSTALLED_APPS` added `'sorl.thumbnail'`

In template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem: I had to add this `files=request.FILES or None,` in the view function

````
    form = PostForm(
        request.POST or None,
        files=request.FILES or None,)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.author = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect("posts:profile", request.user.username)

    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', {'form': form})```
````